# SymPy - Is there a way to write a summation, that has a variable with an incrementing subscript?

Tags: python, indexing, sum, sympy, subscript

I wanted to write this expression, in code:

x<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>2</sub> + x<sub>3</sub> + x<sub>4</sub> + x<sub>5</sub>

I can currently do this via:

```
import sympy as sp
x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 = sp.symbols('x1 x2 x3 x4 x5')
x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5
```

But unfortunately, this doesn't scale very well, incase I wanted to go from x<sub>1</sub> to say, x<sub>10,000</sub>

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

I tried using SymPy's summation function, like this:

```
summation(x(i), (i, 0, n))
```

But unfortunately got a TypeError, stating:

```
'Symbol' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generic IndexedBase symbol with a summation:

```py
>>> i = Symbol('i'); x = IndexedBase('x')
>>> Sum(x[i],(i,1,10))
Sum(x[i], (i, 1, 10))
>>> _.doit()
x[10] + x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] + x[5] + x[6] + x[7] + x[8] + x[9]
```

Comment: Ah perfect smichr! I definitely appreciate the help, really nice compact way of doing it, I'll definitely try this approach out in future similar cases, thanks again (: